# Using the "Additional Fields" added to an external data column in a CQWP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, cqwp

I have a Custom List that I have setup with a column called "Name" which uses the External Data Type.  It is a simple list that returns only one item from my external SQL table which the user selects in Sharepoint via the dropdown.

When I setup the "Name" column as "External Data" I selected additional fields to display by checking their names.  For example I selected a column in my external data table called "CMF_CLIENT".

In the list all the data appears just fine including the "additional fields" that I selected.  The header shows "Name" and then "Name:CMF_CLIENT" with the appropriate data listed below.

I have successfully configured the CQWP and can return the data in the column "Name" from that list (by using "Name [Custom Columns];" but what I would like to do is also include the "additional field" (CMF_CLIENT) as well.  I've tried referencing it in the CQWP like "Name:CMF_CLIENT" as it appears in the list and several variations but I get the error that it "does not exist"...

Is there a way to actually query those additional fields into a CQWP or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to play with it I finally figured it out.

One I was using a reserved name (bad practice).  I changed the name to "Project Name", refreshed the list and then used

"Project Name: CMF_CLIENT" and it worked.  Notice the space in between the : and the CMF_CLIENT.

Love it when you can answer your own question but it's here for reference!